# setq with lambda argument sets symbol's variable cell (or) function cell?

Tags: elisp

```
(setq callback (lambda ()
         (message "hai i am a lambda")))
(funcall callback)

(setq const-val "hai, i am a const")
(message const-val)
```

prints as

```
hai i am a lambda
hai, i am a const
```

Both of them are working perfect. that raises question about `setq` behavior. Does it put the argument value in the symbol's function cell (or) variable cell?

Comment: Did you ask Emacs? What does `C-h f setq` tell you? What does `C-h i`, choose Elisp manual, `i setq` tell you? Such a question is trivial to answer - **`setq` sets a variable's value.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt to first find the answer by asking Emacs.

Comment: @Drew, I dont think that qualify a question for being off topic, and I dont think setq's documentation would have answered OPs question. He seems to be already under the impression that setq should only set the variable value, but is confused about how funcall or quoted symbols work.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: IMO, it should qualify a question as off-topic. A minimum of effort should be required up front, IMHO. At http://english.stackexchange.com/, for instance, questions are routinely closed if they do not "*include the research you've done*". Similarly, StackOverflow requires you to indicate what you've tried so far, to find the answer.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: The *question* posed is not about funcall and quote. It is about "*`setq` behavior*": whether `setq` sets a variable value (cell) or a function value (cell). The confusion you mention might be *behind* the question, but it is not the question. It is this particular question that I vote to close. Questions about `funcall` and `quote` are welcome, of course. Any question is welcome, but IMO this one about `setq` doesn't show any effort to even consult the doc for `setq`. Mine is just one opinion.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: Meta is a better place to discuss whether a close vote is appropriate. I've now posted this topic [there](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/266/105).

Comment: @Drew agreed, thank you for creating the topic.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, thanks a ton for your reply. the first time, i saw `setq` taking a function param, i got surprised which prompted me to raise this qn. and believe me, i am using emacs for 6 months and got a clear understanding of single quote only after seeing the answers. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It places it in the variable cell.  The following example shows the distinction:

```lisp
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq callback (lambda () (message "I am a lambda in a variable cell")))
(lambda nil
  (message "I am a lambda in a variable cell"))

ELISP> (defun callback () (message "I am a function in a function cell"))
callback
ELISP> (funcall callback) ;; Call the function in the variable (expand the symbol)
"I am a lambda in a variable cell"
ELISP> (funcall 'callback) ;; Call the function defined by the symbol
"I am a function in a function cell"
ELISP>
```

Comment: This could use an example of `fset` and the reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html

Answer (score 7):

It always uses the variable cell. You can tell because you are passing `callback`s variable value into `funcall`.

Try running `(funcall 'callback)`, you will get an error, because `callback` has no value as a function, only a variable.

Here you can see the value of your symbols as variables and functions:

```
(setq callback (lambda () (message "hai i am a lambda")))
(setq const-val "hai, i am a const")

(symbol-value 'callback) ;; => (lambda nil (message "hai i am a lambda"))
(symbol-function 'callback) ;; => nil

(symbol-value 'const-val) ;; => "hai, i am a const"
(symbol-function 'const-val) ;; => nil
```